# Why the permutation functions in pytest error may occur (win, pycharm)?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pycharm, pytest

i have Win7-32bit, PyCharm 2016.1.
Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
I start pytest in PyCharm

```
tests.py .Exception in thread MyName:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test-py.test-on-linux-and-windows\background_worker.py", line 23, in task_manager
    func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: t1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

When i permutation *test__is_returned_a_thread* **and** *test__thread_works_in_background* - **no errors**.

Source code https://github.com/patsevanton/test-py.test-on-linux-and-windows

Comment: Can you please provide the code where exception happens?
The error happens because you give no arguments for t1() function.

Comment: @nick_gabpe I added code